# Is there a way to track Facebook users' friend requests (Facebook API)?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I tried to go through Facebook's API to answer this question. Apparently, there are only two similar ways of doing this. One is the invitable_friends api and the other is sending game requests.

They are not exactly what I was looking for, and am particular of tracking users in my app if they already confirmed a certain friend request. I am assuming this is possible since you can track these things on a user's activity log as long as it is shared publicly or by "friends of friends."

Is this currently doable with Facebook's API? If not, is there an alternative approach of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible because there is no endpoint for that in the Graph API IMHO.